# linux rsync iphone photos on connection

Tags: linux, mount, iphone

I'd like to be able to automatically run a script that rsync's my iphone's photo directory to a computer directory in linux whenever I connect via usb. The rsync should be straightforward, assuming I mount correctly, but everywhere I google about how to programmatically mount an iphone takes me to years old pages that want me to compile ifuse. Is there an obvious, easy way to do this?

Comment: Is your question about rsyncing, or about mounting?

Comment: Look into UDEV rules to handle it and call your raync script from. If you get more clear in what part you need help with we could get you more in the right direction.

Comment: I think I know how to edit the udev rules, but the script I would link to would have to know how to mount my iphone. I'm not sure how to do that.